# How to include external HTML in polymer elemets

Tags: polymer

Let's say I have a custom polymer element that is starting to get big. I want to be able to break up the element's template into smaller chunks, move these chunks to other html files and include these chunks in the main template file. Is this possible? Is it a good idea? Is there a convenient way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make more custom elements and include those html files as normal. you can nest custom elements forever.

Comment: these chunks are just plain HTML and not really custom in any way, so I'm hesitant to make them into custom elements. I guess you're saying that the only way to import HTML is to make it into a custom element?

Comment: i do not know if it is the only way. but it is the only way i know. i guess you could look up the html imports standard and see. (i am guessing that is where you would look)